# How to sync audio sample?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, button, windows-8

I have a button that starts playing an audio sample. Now when the user clicks on another button that starts another audio sample, can I set the BPM to the BPM of the first audio sample that is playing? Just like how you mix two audio samples and then you have a sync button so that they mix well together and at they play at the same pace. Do I need an audio library for such functionality? I'm developing for Windows 8 using JavaScript.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I have a done a lot of searching on Google but haven't found anything. I haven't been able to implement anything so far.

Comment: You'll most certainly need a specialized library for this. Beat detection and synchronization can get very complicated very fast.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? I'm trying to do this on react